# Why the second code is safe to make the network call in the map since it is cached?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I'm doing this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines#6) regarding kotlin coroutine. From step 6 to 7 I should update this method:

```
fun getPlantsWithGrowZone(growZone: GrowZone) = liveData {
    val plantsGrowZoneLiveData = plantDao.getPlantsWithGrowZoneNumber(growZone.number) // db
    val customSortOrder = plantsListSortOrderCache.getOrAwait() // network
    emitSource(plantsGrowZoneLiveData.map { plantList ->
        plantList.applySort(customSortOrder)
    })
}
```

To this one:

```
fun getPlantsWithGrowZone(growZone: GrowZone) =
    plantDao.getPlantsWithGrowZoneNumber(growZone.number) // db
        .switchMap { plantList ->
            liveData {
                val customSortOrder = plantsListSortOrderCache.getOrAwait() //network
                emit(plantList.applyMainSafeSort(customSortOrder))
            }
        }
```

The codelab explains the second one difference is that it's safe to make the network call in the map since it is cached. But I can't get why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two goals to making this change to the function, but the second goal is not clearly stated.

1. Do the sorting on a different thread than the main thread, so it doesn't degrade UI performance.
2. Refetch the sorting method from the network each time the database has an update to the plants list, in case the sorting method has changed. In the previous code, the sorting method is only fetched once up front and then reused every time the plants list is updated in the database, so the sort order could be out of date.

---

To achieve goal 1:

Step 1 is creating a version of the sorting function that is a suspend function that doesn't run on the main thread. `withContext` is used in the suspend function to move the sorting to a different thread (specified by using a different dispatcher).

Step 2 is to use this suspend function when mapping the data. The `liveData.map` function's lambda cannot call suspend functions because it is not run in a coroutine. It is run on the main thread directly. So we must change our approach to mapping the data.

Using `switchMap` wrapped around another `liveData { }` coroutine builder block allows us to map the data while also calling suspend functions. The coroutine is encapsulated in the new inner LiveData that's created with the coroutine builder. I believe when they say "cached" they are referring to this inner LiveData object, but the terminology is a little bit vague.

---

To achieve goal 2:

We've already switched to using a `liveData { }` coroutine builder for each change to the database's plant list, so we can go ahead and move this `getOrAwait()` suspend function call inside that inner LiveData so it is made every time.

---

We still have a bit of a problem though. We get the latest sort order every time the database's list changes, but if the database list doesn't change and the sort order does change, it will be left out of date. This would be very complicated to solve with LiveData. But later in the CodeLab, they switch from LiveData to Flow, and solve this using Flow's `combine` operator.